# Stripe - ERROR: elements should be an Elements group. You specified: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a problem while creating a setup for card payment.

```
  const result = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: 'https://example.com/order/123/complete',
    },
  });
```

But receiving an error when submitting:

```
IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmPayment(): elements should be an 
Elements group. You specified: object.
```

I dont know why does it happen because I follow the tutorial steps: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&html-or-react=react#web-submit-payment-details

Playground with the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-forked-wwydkc?file=/src/components/demos/CardForm.js:1073-1245

How to reproduce? Just type in the card input: 4242 4242 4242 4244 and some random valid date and click PAY.

Answer (score 2):

The stripe.confirmPayment() is for Payment Element. Since you are using Card Element, you should call [stripe.confirmCardPayment()](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) instead.